# python selenium send_keys CONTROL, 'c' not copying actual text

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I successfully highlight the section in a web page, but send_keys, `.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")`, does not place the intended text to copy in clipboard, only the last thing I manually copied is in clipboard:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 

driver.get("http://www.somesite.com") 

driver.find_element_by_id("some id").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a") #this successfully highlights section I need to copy 

elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c") # this does not actually copy text**
```

I tried then using the Firefox edit menu to select all and copy text, but didn't work either and cant find anything online to assist other than possible mention of a bug (tried old version of Firefox, but didn't solve issue). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you declaring `elem` anywhere before the `elem.send_keys` line? What happens if you swap this out for `driver.find_element_by_id("some id").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")`?

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much, your suggestion worked. I replaced "elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")" with   "driver.find_element_by_id("ires").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")"

Answer (score 7):

Try using the code below:

Include the header below to import ActionChains

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)

actions.send_keys("c")

actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
```

Comment: For everyone looking at this answer, please note that `.perform()` must be called after each action such as `actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).perform()`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.somesite.com")  
driver.find_element_by_id("some id").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
driver.find_element_by_id("some id").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")
```

Answer (score 3):

This one actually works, it is updated to this date and also tested several times.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


def clear_text(self):
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys("a").perform()
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.DELETE).perform()
```

ActionChains are very useful nowdays, don't forget to `.perform()` every action

To use this functionswhile in a class:

```
text_box.click() #or other clicking function so you are actually typing
self.clear_text()  # Because it stands by itself
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not define what "elim" is
try:

```
elim = driver.find_element_by_id("some_id")
elim.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
elim.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "c")
```

Answer (score 0):

NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined

It means you have to import Keys in your Selenium Project.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```